# MySQL how to find averages / day for different clients with different creation days

Tags: mysql

I've tried the following queries but unfortunately they don't work :(.
Worth mentioning that each customer has more than one CustomerUsers

```
select (a.TotalJobs / b.DaysActive) from
(select count(jr.id) as TotalJobs
from jobrequests jr, customers c, customerusers cu
where jr.customeruserid=cu.id
and cu.customerid=c.id
group by c.name) as a,
(select datediff(curdate(), from_unixtime(c.CreationTime)) as DaysActive
from customers c
group by c.name)  as b
```

Please see below the tables

```
 
Jobs:                  
 +----+--------------+
| ID | JobRequestID |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |            1 | 
|  2 |            1 |
|  3 |            1 |
|  4 |            1 |
|  5 |            1 |
|  6 |            2 |
|  7 |            2 |
|  8 |            3 |
|  9 |            3 |
| 10 |            3 |
| 11 |            4 |
| 12 |            4 |
| 13 |            5 |
| 14 |            5 |
| 15 |            6 |
| 16 |            7 |
| 17 |            8 |
| 18 |            8 |
| 19 |            9 |
| 20 |           10 |
+----+--------------+  
JobRequests:
+----+---------------+
| ID | CustomeUserID |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |             1 |
|  2 |             1 |
|  3 |             2 |
|  4 |             2 |
|  5 |             2 |
|  6 |             3 |
|  7 |             4 |
|  8 |             4 |
|  9 |             4 |
| 10 |             5 |
| 11 |             5 |
| 12 |             5 |
| 13 |             6 |
| 14 |             6 |
| 15 |             7 |
+----+---------------+        

CustomerUsers:
+----+------------+
| ID | CustomerID |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          1 |
|  2 |          1 |
|  3 |          1 |
|  4 |          2 |
|  5 |          2 |
|  6 |          2 |
|  7 |          2 |
|  8 |          3 |
|  9 |          3 |
| 10 |          4 |
+----+------------+

Customers:
+----+------+--------------+
| ID | Name | CreationTime |
+----+------+--------------+
|  1 | a    |   1415814194 |
|  2 | b    |   1415814194 |
|  3 | c    |   1415986994 |
|  4 | d    |   1415986994 |
+----+------+--------------+
```

For the moment it returns 16 results (4X4), dividing each result from 1st sub-query to each result from the 2nd one (each of these sub-queries return 4 results). Can anyone please help me to get this to divide only 1 result from sub-query 1 to it's corespondent from sub-query 2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you can do what you want this a query like this:

```
select c.name, count(*) / (datediff(curdate(), from_unixtime(c.CreationTime))
from customerusers cu join
     jobrequests jr
     on jr.customeruserid = cu.id join
     customers c 
     on cu.customerid = c.id
group by c.name;
```

I don't see why you need two subqueries for this.

Comment: +1, I didn't feel like spending that much brain power, but I completely agree, much better solution...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to `join` your results together -- as currently written, you're producing a `cartesian product`.

Try something like this adding `c.id` to each subquery (it's better to group by it presumably rather than the name):

```
select (a.TotalJobs / b.DaysActive) 
from (
     select c.id, 
            count(jr.id) as TotalJobs
     from jobrequests jr   
          join customers c on jr.customeruserid=cu.id
          join customerusers cu on cu.customerid=c.id
     group by c.id) a join (
          select c.id, 
                 datediff(curdate(), from_unixtime(c.CreationTime)) as DaysActive
          from customers c
          group by c.id) b on a.id = b.id
```

Please note, I've updated your syntax to use the more standard `join` syntax.